# Strange characters appear in admin category and header cart.

Tags: magento-1.9, category, mini-cart

I am facing a very strange problem:

Whenever I go to catalog/category in admin area:

[image]

"c" letter is appear at the first, I know it cause this problem but I don't know how it was appeared.

Otherwise, "c" letter also appear on frontend:

[image: c letter on frontend]

When I was trying to delete an item in minicart, the response html also have c letter.

[image: c letter when deleting an item in minicart]

Please any can help me ?. 
My site: http://sites.magebuzz.com/wholesalersdirect. Enter the postcode as 2500 to redirect to product page.

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `index.php`.  Make sure you don't have a stray "c" at the top before the `<?php`.

If it's not there then try disabling CommerceBug. You may have a stray "c" in that extension somewhere.

Comment: I just checked index.php and disabled CommerceBug but "c" is still there.

Comment: That "c" is above `<!DOCTYPE html>` and is affecting your admin so try checking `app/Mage.php` at the top of that file to see if it's in there.

Comment: Next try `app/etc/local.xml`. Going down the list after that, check the following files: `/includes/config.php`,`/app/Mage.php`,`app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php`,`/lib/Varien/Autoload.php`.

Comment: You can also narrow down your search a bit by opening `app/etc/local.xml` and setting disable_local_modules to true.  `<disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>`

Comment: I just checked Mage.php and nothing happen. "c" letter is still there. I just found that also appear in catalog product grid.

Comment: I just tried to disable local modules as you said. "c" letter is still there. Should I re-upload core magento to server ?

Comment: Yeah couldn't hurt. That way at least you know that it's not in the core. Just make sure you don't have any changes in app/design/frontend/base (or rwd) or skin/frontend/base (or rwd) or those will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I just found a file that contain "c" letter before "?php". That file in community folder.